# disable -enable jframe eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I am trying to Enable my mainJframe after disabling it to use another jFrame. i disable it after : `actionPerformed` with : `frame.setEnabled(false);`  the 2nd jFrame works and closes just fine, but I cant get my mainJframe enabeled again.

```
public class Main {

    JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {...}
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        frame.setBounds(50, 10, 1050, 650);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Something");
        menuBar.add(menu1);

        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("go to frame 2");
        mntmAddStudent.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semilight", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        menu1.add(menuItem1);
        menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {          
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                frame.setEnabled(false); /* ???diable it here or in OtherClass??? */    

                OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass ();
                otherClass .setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    }
}

public class OtherClass extends JFrame {

    private JFrame otherClass;
    public static void main(String[] args) {...}

    public OtherClass() {
        otherClass = new JFrame();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("closing...");
                    JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();

                    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,"Are you sure you to close this frame?","Exit Application",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                ***What do I do here to enable main frame again?***      
                        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                        }
               });
    }
}
```

I also have multiple layouts in main and too many jFrames to change them to jDialogs now.
I am using eclipse Kepler. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you creating a new Main() or you want to use the old one? Then you should not create a new instance. And if yes, try `m.frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you "seem" to have done is create a new instance `Main` and enabled that, instead of enabling the instance you previously disable.

Start by getting rid of `Main m = new Main()`, but unless we have more code to go by, it's impossible to suggest how you would reference the parent frame.

A better solution might be to use a modal `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` as the second window, which would prevent the user from interacting with the first frame until it was closed.

Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses